# two opamp instrumentation amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, instrumentation

I was looking for some instrumentation amplifier, and I've been catched by this one:

[image]

The part number is LT1002.
In the caption it's written:

Gain = R4/R3 * [1 + 1/2*(R2/R1 + R3/R4) + (R2+R3)/R5].

I can't figure out why.
I've tried doing superposition, and using the LKC on the V- node of the first opamp, but I'm stucked for the presence of R5.
Do you have any advice on how to find the correct result?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you start with each OA differential input=0V? I personally would never use it from the difficulty of nulling CM gain with R1 and so much tolerance stackup on DM gain. You might only use with inside a laser trimmed chip.

Comment: No. Let's call the - input V1 and the + input V2. I've started putting V2=0. I have: V1 on the - pin of the first op amp, and 0V on the - pin of the second op amp, for virtual ground. Is it correct? Then I'd like to apply LKC to the - pin of the first op amp.
It seems to me that R5 goes in parallel with R1, but I'm not very confident.

Comment: Virtual gnd means Vin+,Vin- for each Op Amp (OA) input is at same voltage i.e. difference = 0V and not same as 0V gnd.

Comment: Ok,that's true of course. But if I use superposition I have to consider only one of the two voltage sources. I've decided to maintain V1 and to switch off V2. So, if V2=0, V+ of the opamp on the right is 0, and so is V-.
On the other hand I've V1 on v+ and v- of the left opamp . Is that good?

Comment: so far so good.

Comment: If you need an in-amp, I really recommend buying an in-amp.  You never get the same CMRR when you build one.  Further, the two op amp designs make some compromises.

Comment: Yes this seems academic to analyze, but not very useful. I would never use it

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice. But I'd like to figure out where  the formula comes out.
With superposition I get :
Ir1=V1/R1 and Ir5=V1/R5, Ir2= Vout1-V1/R2.
I write the LKC at the node and I get Vout1/V1 . Is it good?

Comment: By the way, why CMRR is not as good as a normal IN-amp?

Comment: If INA has 100 dB CMMR then R1 tuning error must be 0.00001 ratio from ideal

Comment: Show us your derivation in the question, and someone will point out where you're going wrong.

Comment: CMRR isn't as good because you can't match resistance as well as can be done on an IC